# import mysql.connector in flask detected as blueprint

Tags: python, mysql, flask

Im using Flask in python and now i work with bluperints and i have the login page that uses mysql.connector to connect to the database, the problem is that you need to import mysql.connector and to import blueprints you make the folder.file and throw me the error No module named sql becuase thinks that is a Blueprint but is a package.
That worked fine before the blueprints.
This is the code, i have a users.py file were i make the connection to the db and in the other auth.py i import the variables from the connection to be able to make changes to the db with dbcursor.execute

users.py:

```
import mysql.connector
```

auth.py:

```
from users import *
```

error:

File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Python\file1\auth.py", line 2, in 
from users import *
File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Python\file1\users.py", line 1, in 
import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'

Comment: Can you show us the stack trace of the error, and the lines of your code where the error occurs?

Comment: Okay now, edited

Comment: try importing only the blueprints instead of `from users import *`

Comment: Still the same, the problem is that i think when i import the package this specific one have one dot in the middle like the blueprints and in mysql.connector, mysql interrets it like a module

Comment: doesn't that  mean that `mysql` library is not installed ?

Comment: I  have it installed, pip install mysql-connector-python.